# yacc lex when parsing CNC GCODES

Tags: yacc

I have to parse motion control programs (CNC machines, GCODE)

It is GCODE plus similar looking code specific to hardware.

There are lots of commands that consist of a single letter and number,  example:

```
C100Z0.5C100Z-0.5
C80Z0.5C80Z-0.5
```

So part of my (abreviated) lex (racc & rex actually) looks like:

```
A  {[:A,text]}
B  {[:B,text]}
...
Z  {[:Z,text]}
```

So I find a command that takes ANY letter as an argument,  and in racc started typing:

```
letter   : A
         | B
         | C
......
```

Then I stopped,  I haven't used yacc is 30 years,  is there some kind of shortcut for the above?  Have I gone horribly off course?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what are you trying to accomplish. If you want to create Yacc rule that covers all letters you could create token for that:

```
%token letter_token
```

In lex you would find with regular expressions each letter and simply return `letter_token`:

```
Regex for letters {

    return letter_token;
}
```

Now you can use letter_token in Yacc rules:

```
letter   : letter_token
```

Also you haven't said what language you're using. But if you need, you can get specific character you assigned with letter_token, by defining union:

```
%union {

    char c;
}

%token <c> letter_token
```

Let's say you want to read single characters, Lex part in assigning character to token would be:

```
[A-Z] {

    yylval.c = *yytext;
    return letter_token;
}
```

Feel free to ask any further questions, and read more here about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).